# Why TextView intersects with ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-scrollview

Why my TextView intersects with ScrollView at the right side of Activity and how to fix it?

This is screenshot of my Activity.

[image: Example]

This is code XML of my Activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/rules"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_font_tall"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="@string/rules_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_font_medium" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check the property scrollbarStyle of your ScrollView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbarStyle using outsideInset or outsideOverlay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use margin for the second LinearLayout the same way as you used for the first LinearLayout.

```
android:layout_margin="16dp"
```

BTW: as long as the parameters are the same for all of the margins (layout_marginTop, layout_marginBottom, layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight) you can simply use only one attribute: layout_margin

BTW2: Do you really need the parent LinearLayout? you can try it like that:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```